# Display result count of multiple search query in Splunk table

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I want to display a table in my dashboard with 3 columns called Search_Text, Count, Count_Percentage

How do I formulate the Splunk query so that I can display 2 search query and their result count and percentage in Table format.

Example,

```
Heading       Count   Count_Percentage
SearchText1   4       40
SearchText2   6       60
```

The below query will create a column named SearchText1 which is not what I want:

index=something "SearchText1" | stats count AS SearchText1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put each query after the first in an `append` and set the Heading field as desired.  Then use the `stats` command to count the results and group them by Heading.  Finally, get the total and compute percentages.

```
index=foo "SearchText1" | eval Heading="SearchText1"
| append [ | search index=bar "SearchText2" | eval Heading="SearchText2" ]
| stats count as Count by Heading
| eventstats sum(Count) as Total
| eval Count_Percentage=(Count*100/Total)
| table Heading Count Count_Percentage
```

Showing the absence of search results is a little tricky and changes the above query a bit.  Each search will need its own `stats` command and an `appendpipe` command to detect the lack of results and create some.  Try this:

```
index=main "SearchText1" 
| eval Heading="SearchText1" 
| stats count as Count by Heading 
| appendpipe 
    [ stats count 
    | eval Heading="SearchText1", Count=0
    | where count=0 
    | fields - count] 
| append 
    [| search index=main "SearchText2" 
    | eval Heading="SearchText2" 
    | stats count as Count by Heading 
    | appendpipe 
        [ stats count 
        | eval Heading="SearchText2", Count=0
        | where count=0 
        | fields - count] ] 
| eventstats sum(Count) as Total 
| eval Count_Percentage=(Count*100/Total) 
| table Heading Count Count_Percentage
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. How do I get the table to display all the searchText even when count is zero for each of the search text? May be `fillnull`?